# mockito- mocked service does not return true, always returns false

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock

Below code (CallService.java) calls a service called AService and does some update then returns a boolean value.

```
    public boolean getUpdateStatus() throws ServiceException {
    if (finder == null) {
        finderBean = new FinderBean();
    }
    myService = finderBean.find(AService.class);
    if (myService == null) {
        System.out.println("null >>>>>>>");
    }

    final Config config = new Config();
    final Update update = new Update();
    status = myService.update(update, config);
    System.out.println("Status: " + status);
    return status;
}
```

And below test case validates the CallService.java; have mocked all the service related classes and calling my class under test to call the AService and asserting the bolean, but mock always returns false, regardless of mocking.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    myService = PowerMockito.mock(AService.class);
    finderBean = PowerMockito.mock(FinderBean.class);

    update = PowerMockito.mock(Update.class);
    config = PowerMockito.mock(Config.class);       
PowerMockito.whenNew(FinderBean.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(finderBean);

PowerMockito.when(finderBean.find(AService.class)).thenReturn(myService);
}

@Test
public void TestUpdateState() throws Exception {

    callService = new CallService();
    MemberModifier.field(CallService.class, "finderBean").set(callService, finderBean);
    PowerMockito.when(finderBean.find(AService.class)).thenReturn(myService);
    PowerMockito.when(myService.update(update, config)).thenReturn(true);

    final boolean status = callService.getUpdateStatus();
    assertTrue(status);
}
```

Am I missing something here, any pointers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#introduction)

> All usages require `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest` **annotated at class level**.
>
> #### Use PowerMockito.whenNew, e.g.
>
> ```
> whenNew(MyClass.class).withNoArguments().thenThrow(new IOException("error message"));
> ```
>
> Note that you must prepare the class creating the new instance of `MyClass` for test, not the `MyClass` itself. E.g. if the class doing `new MyClass()` is called `X` then you'd have to do `@PrepareForTest(X.class)` in order for `whenNew` to work:

***emphasis mine***

So make sure you have the necessary attributes are in place and that the dependencies are mocked accordingly

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CallService.class)
public class TestMyClass {
    FinderBean finderBean;
    AService myService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {        
        myService = PowerMockito.mock(AService.class);
        finderBean = PowerMockito.mock(FinderBean.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(FinderBean.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(finderBean);            
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestUpdateState() throws Exception {
        //Arrange                      
        PowerMockito.when(finderBean.find(AService.class)).thenReturn(myService);
        PowerMockito.when(myService.update(any(Update.class), any(Config.class))).thenReturn(true);
        CallService callService = new CallService(); 
    
        //Act
        final boolean status = callService.getUpdateStatus();

        //Assert
        assertTrue(status);
    }
}
```

The reason it was not working before with your mock services was because the arguments in the test were not the same arguments in the method under test. The method under test was creating its own instances locally which would mean that they would be different instances to those used in the test setup and as such would not behave as expected when invoked.

Comment: thank you, i have mocked update and config classes and passed as arguments to the update method on myService as below which was causing issue. PowerMockito.when(myService.update(update, config)).thenReturn(true);  now using with any(Update.class),any(Config) solved the issue. But could you point out why it was not working with mocked classes?